# pause excel VBA until user saves a copy of a file

Tags: excel, vba

What is the correct syntax for pausing a `VBA` until the user saves an excel attachment?  In the `VB` below the user is prompted upon opening the workbook with a selection, if that selection is yes then another message box appears asking them to fill out a form and save. I am trying to pause the `VB` until save is clicked.  However, I am getting many compile errors currently.  The lines with a `** **` were added to try and accomplish thisThank you :).

**VB**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim WS As Worksheet, Rng As Range, c As Range
Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
Dim Msg As String, Addr As String, FName As String, i As Long
Dim obj As Object
**Dim MyDoc As Document**
Dim MyFileCopy As String
Dim intAnswer As Integer

'define path
 MyFileCopy = "L:\NGS\HLA LAB\total quality management\QC & QA\DOSE reports\DOSE reporting form Attachment.xlsx"

'open sheet
 Sheets("Email").Activate
 intAnswer = MsgBox("Are there any issues to report", vbYesNoCancel)
  Select Case intAnswer
  Case vbYes
  Range("D2").Value = "x"
  MsgBox ("Please select an issue and save"), vbExclamation

  'create a separate sheet2 to mail out and pause VB
   Sheets(2).Copy
   Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
   With wkb
   **Set MyDoc = Documents.Add
   MyDoc.SaveAs "MyFileCopy.xlsx"
   DoEvents
   Do
   Loop Until MyDoc.Saved
     .Close True**
   End With

  Case vbCancel
  Application.SendKeys "%{F11}", True

  Case Else
  Range("C2").Value = "x"
  End Select

'create connection, check condition, send email
 Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
 Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Email")
With WS
 Set Rng = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With

 For Each c In Rng

 Msg = "For " & WS.Cells(2, 2) & Chr(14) & Chr(14)
 For i = 3 To 4
 If LCase(WS.Cells(2, i)) = "x" Then
    Msg = Msg & "   -" & WS.Cells(1, i) & Chr(14)
 End If
Next

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    With OutMail
        .To = c
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Daily Operational Safety Briefing"
        .Body = Msg
        If Range("D2").Value & Chr(14) = "x" Then .Attachments.Add MyFileCopy, 1
        .Send
    End With
Next c

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

'confirm message sent, clear sheet, and delete copy
 MsgBox "The data has been emailed sucessfully.", vbInformation
 Range("C2:D2").ClearContents
 Kill MyFileCopy


'Exit and do not save
 Application.Quit
 ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False
 End Sub
```

Comment: To fix the error in that line you'll need to add a reference to "Microsoft Word * Object Library" (in VBA editor go to Tools -> References... and place a checkmark in it)

Comment: I get `ActiveX component can't create object` with the `Set MyDoc = Documents.Add` selected.  Thank you :).

Comment: is there a better way to do this as the attachment is an xlsx.  Thank you :).